# How to make Multisite global login that redirects to correct subsite after login

Tags: multisite

Installed wordpress multisite and  created created number of subsites so i want to make a global login page and after successful login need to redirect to correct subsites based on the user credentials.

Is there any way to do this

Comment: Can you provide some detail about what you've already tried here? Is your multisite subdomain or subdirectory? What happens if a user is registered to more than one site? There are a lot of unknowns and your question is very vague, you'll be more likely to get help if you can be more specific.

Comment: My multisite installation is subdomain . So i want to make a global login url like http://example.com/login  and   lets say different subdomain are demo1.example.com  , demo2.example.com   . And  these subdomain admin user can use same login url http://example.com/login   for admin login instead of http://demo1.example.com/wp-admin ,  http://demo2.example.com/wp-admin and based on  user credentials they used for login need to redirect to respective subdomain admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on my local with a fresh subdmoain setup. Here's my setup:

- Created `subdomain.test`
- Added site: `demo1.subdomain.test` with the admin user `demo1`
- Added site: `demo2.subdomain.test` with the admin user `demo2`

Now, if I go to `http://subdomain.test/wp-login.php` and login, I get the following results:

- User `demo1` logs in to http://subdomain.test/wp-login.php and is redirected to http://demo1.subdomain.test/wp-admin/
- User `demo2` logs in to http://subdomain.test/wp-login.php and is redirected to http://demo2.subdomain.test/wp-admin/

In short, WordPress already does this for you, assuming that the admin users for your subdomains are only admins for those sites.

Comment: oh really .. but do not know why my setup does not works. i tried this already may be some plugin plugin conflicts ... i am using  Hide My WP plugin